# Google functions correct IAM settings to prevent 403 Error for nested resources

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-functions, http-status-code-403, google-cloud-iam

I have a React JS and deployed it as a function in GC. It looks I have some permission problem even though I gave "Cloud Functions Admin" and "Service Account User" access to the project
Basically it does not access to anything inside build folder of the react project. Does the given permission is not enough? how could I give access to the functions and all the resources location inside the function recursively to have access to all files and folders via http call?

[image: google chrome debug]

Comment: Not sure I understand - is the error at deployment time? or at invocation time?

Comment: When you deployed the function, which authorization settings did you configure? Edit your question with the deploy command. The error is 403 and looks to come from a web browser. That means Cloud IAP is enforcing authorization on clients.

Comment: Yes John that was the problem.

Comment: Please check if you have correct role assigned to the cloud function you are running. You can enable permissions by selecting the cloud function and clicking on Permissions on the top. For more info regarding IAM, please refer to the [following article](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#cloud-functions-roles).